# How to determine QRS voltage from ECG?

Tags: cardiology, physiology, electrocardiogram, cardiac-physiology

Attached below is a question from my textbook "Guyton and Hall Textbook of Medical Physiology Review, 4e" and I am confused because the solutions manual has the answer as B (0.5mV), implying that it only took the R wave into consideration for determining the QRS voltage. I remain convinced that the answer should be A (0.05mV) as the Q and S must also be accounted in calculations.

My logic:

R:0.9, Q:-0.15, S:-0.3 = net: 0.45

I+III=II

0.4+I=0.45

What do you think the right answer is? can you please correct me and help me understand the right way of approaching such a question?

Many thanks in advance!

[image: ECG question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Einthoven’s Law

From [ECG and Echo Learning](https://ecgwaves.com/topic/ekg-ecg-leads-electrodes-systems-limb-chest-precordial/#:%7E:text=Einthoven%27s%20law.,in%20lead%20I%20and%20III.):

> This law implies that the sum of the potentials in lead I and lead Ill equals the potentials in lead II. In clinical electrocardiography, this means that the amplitude of, for example, the R-wave in lead Il is equal to the sum of the R-wave amplitudes in lead I and III.

So the law uses the R wave, which is the upward deflection above the isoelectric line.

[image: ECG tracing with coloured waves]

Image from [Geeky Medics](https://geekymedics.com/understanding-an-ecg/).

Einthoven’s law can be summarised as `I + III = II`.

## Solution

In the ECG you provide, the lead II R-wave has a voltage of 0.9mV. The given value for III is 0.4.

Thus:

`I + 0.4 = 0.9`

`I = 0.9 - 0.4`

`I = 0.5`

So the R-wave voltage in lead I is 0.5mV.

---

## Discussion

Your method of finding the net value of the positive and negative deflections will yield the **net deflection**, but it is not the net deflection that follows Einthoven’s law.

I think of this as the R wave is the only part of the waveform where the potential difference is positive in the direction of that lead.

---

**Other reference**

[ECG and Echo Learning](https://ecgwaves.com/ecg-qrs-complex-q-r-s-wave-duration-interval/)

Comment: Oh I get it now! Thank you so much!!
So basically:
Mean Electrical Axis: you use net QRS voltage
Einthoven’s Law: you use R wave amplitude

Comment: Yes that seems to be it - It has been years since I studied this but looking at it again that seems to be the way to do it.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much!